# Custom PDF template in Commerce Billy

Tags: commerce

I have installed [Commerce Billy](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy) module on my website.

Then upon ordering I get this PDF with this layout.[image]

But I want to change the table displayed, because I've created some custom fields in it and I want to display it also in the table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This table is actually the rendered view 'Line items (Commerce Line Item)' which is created in code by Drupal Commerce. So all you have to do is to modify this view to your needs.

To further customize the display of your invoice, you can make a copy of `css/pdf.css` and `themes/commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php` located in `commerce_billy_pdf` folder into your custom theme and experiment.

Comment: Great answer. Small note, the folder name in the billy module folder is now `template` not `theme`. Do you know how to preview the template as HTML before it's passed to the PDF generator? If you do I've [asked that as a follow-up question here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214447/how-to-view-and-inspect-a-commerce-billy-invoice-pdf-template-as-html-before-it)

Comment: Any idea on the preprocess function for this theme registered under billy ?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to display field output from custom fields, the simplest way is to put tokens in one of the `admin/commerce/config/billy-invoice/pdf` text areas.
I regularly place the pdf footer text in the `commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php` and use the footer text area to place text and tokens like `Customer ID: [current-user:field-customer-id]` and do the styling and placement via CSS.