# Add payment method to Billy PDF?

Tags: files, commerce

Is there a way to add a billing method/status line to invoice, generated by module [Commerce Billy PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy)?

I've been looking for a way for days and still cannot figure it out......

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114620/custom-pdf-template-in-commerce-billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the template directory of Billy PDF (commerce_billy/modules/commerce_billy_pdf/templates) and copy the file

```
commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php
```

to your theme directory. Thats the template of the generated pdf. You can simply edit this template and add the billing method i think.

You can access the order object via

```
$order = commerce_order_load($variables['elements']['#entity']->order_id);
```

inside of the template.

Comment: As a side note, there is no need to load the order object since it is already provided via the the $variables array (i.e., $variables['commerce_order'])